# Select based on existence of particular value after given value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table 'Users' as follows.

```
UserID       Status       Effective Date
-------------------------------------------
0111         Rehire       5 Apr 2021
0111         Resign       4 Apr 2021
0111         Transfer     10 Mar 2021
0111         Hire         5 Aug 2014
0112         PayrollChange 4 Apr 2021
0112         Resign       3 Apr 2021
0112         Hire         1 Jul 2001
0113         Resign withdraw 3 Apr 2021
0113         Resign       1 Apr 2021          
0113         Transfer     1 Nov 2019
0113         Hire         10 Aug 2007
```

I would like create a SQL query to identify those users who got resigned (need not be the latest record) but not rehired or resignation withdrawn. Considering an employee can resign and withdraw multiple times. Need to consider based on effective date. How can I create such a script.

Output expected

```
UserID       Status       Effective Date
-------------------------------------------
0112         Resign       3 Apr 2021
```

Please help on the same.

Note: I have tried multiple times and unable to arrive at a proper query. Hence posting this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DaleK I have tried multiple times and multiple queries. Unable to arrive at a correct answer. Hence posting.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Users U1
WHERE U1.Status = 'Resign' 
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                      FROM Users U2
                      wHERE U2.UserId = U1.UserId
                            AND U2.Status IN ('Rehire', 'Resign withdraw'))
```

---

Comment: I have tried this. Still no luck. Can you please read my edited question

Comment: Your `not in` should be `in` since you have a `not exists`

Comment: @Erma . . . This could return duplicates if user resigns multiple times with no "Rehire" or "Resign withdrawn" after the resignations.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like create a SQL query to identify those users who got resigned (need not be the latest record) but not rehired or resignation withdrawn.

If I understand correctly, you want to compare the maximum of the resigned date to the maximum of the other dates:

```
select userId, 'Resign',
       max(case when status = 'Resign' then EffectiveDate end)
from t
where max(case when status = 'Resign' then EffectiveDate end) > max(case when status in ('Rehire', 'Resign withdraw') then EffectiveDate end) or
      max(case when status in ('Rehire', 'Resign withdraw') then EffectiveDate end) is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

So here's one approach that you can try, given you simply want to find any user with a status of "Resign" but exclude any that also have a status of "Rehire" or "Resign withdraw" - you can simply assign a suitable value to each and sum them for each user and filter accordingly; the effective date will always be the most recent date with the required status. This will be the better performing query given a suitable index.

```
select UserId, 'Resign' Status, EffectiveDate from (
    select 
        Sum(case when status in ('Rehire','Resign withdraw') then 1000 when status='Resign' then 1 else 0 end) Stot,
        Max( case when status='resign' then Effectivedate end) EffectiveDate,
        UserId
    from T
    where Status in ('Rehire', 'Resign withdraw', 'Resign' )
    group by UserId
)x
where Stot>0 and Stot<1000
```